# How to prove that $\mathbb{P} = \operatorname{Spec}( k[q] ) \cup \operatorname{Spec}( k[q^{-1}] )$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the paper [on crystal bases](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/kashiwara/on-crystal.pdf).

Let $k$ be a field. On page $11$, it is said that $\mathbb{P} = \operatorname{Spec}( k[q] ) \cup \operatorname{Spec}( k[q^{-1}] )$. How to prove this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $\Bbb P$ the projective line?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, yes, $\mathbb{P}$ is the projective line.

Comment: It's just the classical construction of $\Bbb P^1$ as gluing of scheme. (If you want a reference see Harshtorne II.2). Topologically, you're gluing two copy of $k$ along $k^*$ by the map $\phi : k^* \to k^*, z \mapsto 1/z$.